# TextArea scrolling pauses timerEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a TimerEvent that makes a shape's alpha change every second:

```
private function changeLightStatus(e:TimerEvent):void{
    if (boolFlashOn == false){
        light.alpha = 1;
        boolFlashOn = true;
    }else{
        light.alpha = 0.5;          
        boolFlashOn = false;
    }
```

No issues, it works fine, but I have a `<s:TextArea/>` underneath and when the user scrolls it the timer pauses and the shape stops flashing.

I've had a look at other questions and the answers say to make a new time thread so that they aren't connected, but apparently I can't do this in Flash Builder (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Thanks in advance

Comment: _`"I have a TimerEvent... No issues, it works fine"`_ so don't just show us the **working** timer code... Something in your `mouse_over` code is causing a timer stop, silent error or even crash. What does debugger say? Any warning about an undefined or null variable?

Comment: There is no mouse over code. I'm using a standard <s:TextArea/> which has scrolling if there is too much text. When I scroll the timer stops the event. No error, no crashes and nothing in debugger. As soon as I stop scrolling it runs again. Also I put the timer event code in case anyone had another method as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your tags to include Flex, but unfortunately I only ever use pure AS3 (no Flex tags).

So while you wait for a better answer you could try...

**(1)** 
When you `addChild(light)`, also set as: `light.mouseChildren = light.mouseEnabled = false;`.

**(2)** 
Otherwise consider `EnterFrame` instead of `Timer`:

```
//# add to initial setup of vars...
var counter:int = 0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
```

Then add supporting function

```
private function onEnterFrame (e:Event) : void
{
    if ( count >= 50)
    {
        if (boolFlashOn == false)
        { light.alpha = 1; boolFlashOn = true; }

        else
        { light.alpha = 0.5; boolFlashOn = false; }

        count = 0; //reset for next loop
    }

    count++
}
```

Let me know how it goes...

Comment: Thanks for the ideas VC, but unfortunately no luck. Used both ideas and no difference. My guess is that when the textArea is scrolled it pauses the timeline. Think I need a way of restarting the timeline once scrolling has begun.

Comment: I hear you but that still seems like a strange "feature". Could be a possible bug... Does it still pause if `light` is positioned elsewhere (not over text)? I will try to recreate the issue if you still got no Answer by later today.

Comment: I actually have four lights and all of them get effected. I have found an alternative to fix this issue. If I make a group with a scroller (again with flex) for some reason that scroller won't effect the timeline. No idea why.  Once I get it tidy I'll put it on here for anyone else. Still it would be interesting to find out why the textArea works differently.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using a text Area I made this:

```
<s:Group width="{this.width*0.8}" height="{this.height*0.175}" top="{this.height*0.475}" horizontalCenter="0">
    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Scroller>
        <s:Group width="{this.width*0.8}" height="{this.height*0.175}" top="{this.height*0.475}" horizontalCenter="0">  
            <s:Label id="lblInfo" color="0x000000" width="{this.width*0.8}"/>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Group>
```

This made a very basic box where the user can scroll through text and wouldn't affect my timerEvent.

I would still like to know the reason why the textArea pauses the timeline. I made a very simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private var tmrTest : Timer = new Timer(100);
        private var boolTest : Boolean = false;

        private function init():void{

            tmrTest.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, testChange)
            tmrTest.start();
        }

        private function testChange(e:TimerEvent):void{
            if (boolTest == false){
                btnTest.label = "Bye";
                boolTest = true;
            }else{
                btnTest.label = "Hi";
                boolTest = false;
            }
        }

    ]]> 
</fx:Script>

<s:Button id="btnTest" label="Hi" width="{this.width*0.5}" height="{this.height*0.1}"/>

<s:Group width="{this.width*0.8}" height="{this.height*0.175}" top="{this.height*0.475}" horizontalCenter="0">
    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Scroller>
        <s:Group width="{this.width*0.8}" height="{this.height*0.175}" top="{this.height*0.475}" horizontalCenter="0">  
            <s:Label color="0x000000" width="{this.width*0.8}"
                     text="{'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng'}"/>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Group>

<s:TextArea width="{this.width*0.8}" height="{this.height*0.175}" top="{this.height*0.725}" horizontalCenter="0" editable="false"
            text="{'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng'}"/>
```

I probably should have mentioned before that this was running it on an iPhone, not a simulator. The simulator didn't give me any problems and I haven't tried android.

Comment: Just changed the skinclass of the textArea to a spark component instead of a mobile and it didn't freeze the timer. So I'm assuming this is an issue with the richEditableText component which is used in the mobile skinclass. If my research is correct the richEditableText isn't actually part of the stage it's layered over top, which has caused me issues in the past.